# How can I prove that the following polynomial is equal to $a=\frac{pb}{bc-ad}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The problem states: 

When $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is divided by $(x-a)$ the remainder is $p$, and when divided by $(x+a)$ the remainder is $-p$. Prove that $a=\frac{pb}{bc-ad}$.

I went ahead and started doing long division:
$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rll}
    ax^2 && \hbox{} \\[-3pt]
   (x-a) \enclose{longdiv}{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}\kern-.2ex \\[-3pt]
      \underline{ax^3-a^2x^2\phantom{3333333}} && \hbox{} \\[-3pt]
      \phantom{0} && \hbox{} \\[-3pt]
      \underline{\phantom{0}\phantom{0}} && \hbox{} \\[-3pt]
      \phantom{0} && \hbox{} \\[-3pt]
      \underline{\phantom{0}} && \hbox{} \\[-3pt]
      \phantom{00}
  \end{array}
$$

I stopped there didnt go any further because I know it will be hectic. Am I overthinking this? Please help.

Comment: use the Remainder Theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In other words, you actually know that $P(a)=p$ and that $P(-a)=-p$. This tells you $$a^4+ba^2+ca+d=p$$ $$-a^4+ba^2-ca+d=-p$$

Summing both equalities, we obtain $2ba^2+2d=0$.
Now if $b=0$ we are done.

Otherwise, taking the difference of the two equations, we get $2a^4+2ca=2p$. We then write $a^4=(a^2)a^2=-\frac{da^2}{b}$. We obtain $a(c-\frac{da}{b})=p$, and we deduce then $$a=\frac{pb}{bc-ad}$$ (provided that $bc-ad$ is not zero).

Comment: I'm kinda confused at how you got $\frac{da^2}{b}$ and $a(c-\frac{da}{b})$

Comment: Well, by summing the equalities I obtained $a^2=-\frac{d}{b}$. Then, I write $a^4$ as the product of $a^2$ with itself, and I replace only one $a^2$ by the above expression. Thus, I have $a^4+ca=p \iff -\frac{da^2}{b}+ca=p \iff a(c-\frac{da}{b})=p$ after factorizing by $a$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for your help.